GET request with Angular 17, how to do it?
I'm currently learning Angular CLI, and I would like to fetch an image from my server.
I tried following some tutorials but they don't provide much information on what is happening, and most of them are using a file called app.module.ts not available in latest angular versions.
Here is the step-by-step of what I have done so far:

Set up an express server that is properly serving the JSON object with all the images' name and path.

Set-up a new service to provide the GET request API using the HttpClient library, here what it looks like:


cards.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CardsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000')
  }
}




Set up my cards.component.ts to be able to use the services:

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CardsService} from '../services/cards.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cards',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './cards.component.html',
  styleUrl: './cards.component.css'
})
export class CardsComponent {
  posts:any;

  constructor(private service:CardsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(response => {
        this.posts = response;
      });
  }
}


I really don't know how to follow-up from here, I would like to use my HTML file now to properly request the imagem from the server.
Here is my cards.component.html:
<div class="cards">

  <div class="card">
    <img src="/src/assets/img/card0.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="/src/assets/img/card1.png" />
  </div>

</div>


How do I use the API to get the images from the server and replace the <img src="/src/img/card0.png" /> for a proper GET request from the server?
from the guide I was following, it does the following for html:
<ul class="list-group">
  <li 
      *ngFor="let post of posts"
      class="list-group-item">
      {{ post.title }}
  </li>
</ul>

I don't understand where is the API call in the code above to be able to properly use in my project
Edit:
Here are some screenshots of the error:
image not loading

server 404 error: (



probably /src part is not needed there (or even /src/assets/)

but it shows the image correctly on my IDE when I hover over the path (in webstorm it means the image path is correctly assigned I believe)

NOT it's without "src". it's true that you can see the img when you add src (it's relate a kind of "cache" but it's wrong). Remember: Angular copy your folder "assets" in the same folder than the index.html is. So you should use "assets/img0.png" or "/assets/img0.png" (if you use the "/" it's a position absolute, so related to the www.yourdominio.com, if not it's according the base href -it's the same when base href is /-)

I do not get your question. There is nothing common between the service and the images. Speaking about images. If you create a new project via Angular CLI it will create for you an assets folder under the sec folder and next to the app folder. The structure of the initial project should look like this:
src
+-app
+-assets
angular.json

Also, Angular will create for you angular.json file in the root of your application, next to the src folder (not inside it!). This is the file containing the configuration for your angular project - more about it you can find here. One of the things you can find in the config is the location of the assets folder. It is under:
projects: {
  images: {
    architect: {
      build: {
        options: {
          assets: [
            "src/favicon.ico",
            "src/assets"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

By default Angular will point to assets folder under the src folder. You can put any images there and refer to them in your application. For your card component, if you put your images in the assets folder, and if your application has this structure:
src
+-app
| +-card.component.html
| +-card.component.css
| +-cart.component.ts
+-assets
  +-card0.png
  +-card1.png

you can refer to the images like this:
<div class="cards">

  <div class="card">
    <img src="../assets/card0.png" />
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img src="../assets/card1.png" />
  </div>

</div>


I have updated my question with a few pictures displaying my issue, hopefully it's a bit clearer now. I was following this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7BJFTEbc10 . He also has some pictures on his src/assets/  folder and as to fetch from the server, but he's doing some advanced api set-up, I would like to do by the simplest way possible, to understand the fundamentals.

NOT you need remove the "../". Angular copy the assets folder in the same folder than the index.html is (you can change this default changing the angular.json).

I see you are trying to map the response data from your api, so the first thing is to define the response model of the api. I'm going to assume that your api returns you an array of images, then your model would be something like:
export interface IResponseImages {
    src: string
}

Then your component would look like this:
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CardsService} from '../services/cards.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-cards',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [],
    templateUrl: './cards.component.html',
    styleUrl: './cards.component.css'
})
export class CardsComponent {
    posts:IResponseImages[];

    constructor(private service:CardsService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getData().subscribe({
            next:(response:IResponseImages[])=>{
                this.posts = response;
            }
        });
    }
}

In your hmtl you could have something like this:
<div class="cards">
    <div *ngFor="let card of cards" class="card">
        <img [src]="card" />
    </div>
</div>

